# Thymeleaf & Springboot errors

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, replace, thymeleaf

On my VPS The problem occurs when going to the page, but on my local machine it has no issues of loading.

Error:

```
2021-01-10 22:57:19.998 ERROR 46 --- [nio-1059-exec-7] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-1059-exec-7] Exception processing template "player": Error resolving template [/player/general], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "player" - line 94, col 18)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/player/general], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "player" - line 94, col 18)
```

Code:

```
<div th:replace="'/player/' + ${page} :: ${page}"></div>
```

Comment: which template resolver are you using? if it is ClassLoaderTemplateResolver, you have to make sure that the folder /player is in your classpath.

Comment: Its in the /player folder path in my templates, its goes from player.html -> /player/ -> general.html

Comment: which templateResolver are you using? can you paste your configuration of the template resolve?

Comment: don't think i'm using a template resolver.

Comment: there must be a template resolver, i guess you are using the default one if you did not configure anything by yourself. can you tell us where is your folder: player? if you can provide your project structure, it may help others to help you in an efficient way.